# How to write a sql to generate same id column when any of three columns is the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table T1 like below:

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    1    1
 1    2    1
 1    2    3
 4    4    4
```

We want to generate one more column, and then new table T2 is like below:

```
col1 col2 col3  id
 1    1    1    1
 1    2    1    1
 1    2    3    1
 4    4    4    2
```

The first three rows has at lease one same value in col1/col2/col3, so they have the same id 1. For example, row1 and row3 have same value 1 in col1, so they have the same id. The forth row don't have any same value with the first three row in col1/col2/col3, so it have a new id 2.

To be more percise, when T1 have one more column (4,2,4) like below, all rows have same id 1.

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    1    1
 1    2    1
 1    2    3
 4    4    4
 4    2    4
```

My Idea:
1、We can join table T1 with itself to eliminate different rows

```
select * from T1 t11 join T1 t12 on t11.col1 = t12.col1 or t11.col2 = t12.col2 or t11.col3 = t12.col3.
```

```
t11.col1 t11.col2 t11.col3 t12.col1 t12.col2 t12.col3
   1         1       1        1         1       1
   1         1       1        1         2       1
   1         1       1        1         2       3

   1         2       1        1         1       1
   1         2       1        1         2       1
   1         2       1        1         2       3

   1         2       3        1         1       1
   1         2       3        1         2       1 
   1         2       3        1         2       3 

   4         4       4        4         4       4
```

2、Maybe we can distinct or group by the result above, but I don't kown how to do?

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: Imagine. 1st row is (1,2,3) and is assigned id=1. 2nd row is (5,4,3), it has the same value in 3rd column and hence is assigned with the same id=1. 3rd row is (5,6,7), it has the same value in 1st column and hence is assigned with the same id=1. Now look at 1st and 3rd rows which have the same id=1: (1,2,3) and (5,6,7). Nothing common...

Comment: Suppose the 4d row is (4,2,4). Whis one is the correct grouping: 3 rows with col1=1 or 3 rows with col2=2? You should be more precise on the rules  you want.

Comment: @Akina，In this situation, 1st and 3rd have the same id.

Comment: @Serg, All the row have the same id 1.

Comment: AS the most first step - collect all values per column for the rows which must have the same id value: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=adc6f8e9637b2b800f8ecbbe75f050a2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your table is lacking a fourth column which provides the suggested ordering of the records.  For the purpose of this answer, I will assume that there exists an `id` column as follows:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3
1  | 1    | 1    | 1
2  | 1    | 2    | 1
3  | 1    | 2    | 3
4  | 4    | 4    | 4
```

We can use analytic functions here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN col1 = col2 AND col2 = col3 AND col1 = col3
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS val
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col1, col2, col3, SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_col
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

This question can be model as graph problem and can be solved by UnionFind algorithm Or GraphX API `connectedComponents` in [GraphX Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#graph-operators).

Considering ConnectedComponents may need lots of shuffle in Spark, we use UDAF `collect_list` to collect all data to one node and use UnionFind implemented by UDF to solve this question. This consume less than 1 second on 1000,000 nodes and 10,000,000 edges on UDF thanks to UnionFind Complexity is O(nlogn). However, UnionFind consume a Int Array whose size is 1000,000. This comsume 4M Bytes.

One more tricky problem is the building of edges for nodes. ConnectedComponents and UnionFind takes edges instead of nodes as input. We first use nested Loop to build edges and unexpectedly found it comsume 50+ seconds for 1000,000 nodes because its Complexity is O(n^2). Inspired by Join implementation of SparkSQL, we find that we can also use sort or hashmap to build edges. We choose hasmap to build edge, which tasks 5 seconds and some memory.